# Cannot resolve symbol 'BottomNavigationItemView' in androidx

Tags: android, android-support-library, androidx, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomnavigationview

I removed `implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'` and migrated to androidx `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0-alpha01'` I like to know what is the equivalent code for BottomNavigationItemView.

`    public void hideOrShowBottomNavigationItem(int id, BottomNavigationView view, int visibility) {

```
    BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) view.getChildAt(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
        BottomNavigationItemView itemView = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);
        if (itemView.getId() == id) {
            itemView.setVisibility(visibility);
        }
    }
}` i am getting error cannot resolve BottomNavigationItemView
```

Comment: Check the import in your classes

Answer (score 1):

Check the right imports in your project:

```
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationItemView
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
```